# Multiple instances of Files

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files

Is it possible to open more than one instance of Files (pantheon-files)? Right now, every time i open Files new tab is created instead of new window. I use Elemntary Loki, have installed Tweaks but didn't found any setting to change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming it is the same for Loki (0.4)...I am running Freya (0.3.2)

1. open files ... it now exists on the dock
2. right click on files in the dock
3. select new window
4. you should now have a separate window for files

Comment: thanks for your response. Do you think there is a way do set this as default behavior? For example every time i hit shortcut for File new window pops up?

Answer (score 0):

With Files running (and open and focussed) hitting Ctrl+N will open a Files new window.

Comment: Yes, this of course works. But suppose I've Files opened in first workspace and currently am working in fifth workspace. So I need to find in wkich workspace Files are opened, focus the window and hit CTRL+N - lots of work :) It would be ideally if new window opens every time i press for example Super+F.

Comment: Another workround is to go to System Settings/Keyboard/Shortcuts and set up a custom short cut which launches pantheon-files (with or without a start directory).  If launched this way, a new Files window will open in the current workspace.

Comment: I did this and unfortunately new tab is opened instead.

Comment: Apologies, when using a custom shortcut, an explicit path must be given as a parameter in order for new window to open.  I am not sure why.

Comment: Indeed, it solved my problem, i just set shortcut for `pantheon-files /home/myuser` and now new windows is opened each time, thx :)